# Prolog - Print list of lists with format/2

Tags: printing, grid, prolog, format

This is the code I use:

```
printElement(L/C) :- format('~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', [L, C]).
printElement(L) :- format('~t~a~t~20+|~t', L).

printList([]) :- format('~n', []).

printList([H|T]) :-
    printElement(H),
    printList(T).

printLists([], _).
printLists([H|T], N) :-
    M is N + 1,
    format('~d- |', M),
    printList(H),
    printLists(T, M).
```

Being *BL* a list of lists I call the predicate as `printLists(BL, 0).`

My goal is to display *BL* as a 9x9 grid with the cells as the same size.
Instead I got this:

[image: output1]

I want all columns to be displayed as the first column in the image, I mean I want all the other cells to have the same width.

Why does not my code work for the second column and so on?

Comment: Here's another work-around to try which I played with and works in SWI Prolog: `printElement(L) :- format('~0+~t~a~t~20+|', L).` and `printElement(L/C) :- format('~0+~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', [L, C]).`. Let me know if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach which uses a predicate that builds the format string (actually, an atom) and an updated data list based upon an input row. This circumvents the issue of multiple formats per row by building the single format string for an entire row so that a single `format/2` can be called for each row.

```
% makeFormat/4
% makeFormat(-RowData, -FormatPrefix, +NewRowData, +Format)
%
makeFormat([], F0, [], F) :-
    atom_concat(F0, '~n', F).
makeFormat([E|Es], F0, L, F) :-
    (   E = A/B
    ->  atom_concat(F0, '~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', F1),
        L = [A,B|Ls]
    ;   atom_concat(F0, '~t~a~t~20+|', F1),
        L = [E|Ls]
    ),
    makeFormat(Es, F1, Ls, F).

printLists([], _).
printLists([H|T], N) :-
    M is N + 1,
    makeFormat(H,'~d- |',  H1, Format),  % make format starting with '~d- |'
    format(Format, [M|H1]),              % write out the list with prefix
    printLists(T, M).
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!
You had an inconsistency on the arguments of `makeformat/4`.
On `printLists/2` you are calling `makeformat/4` 's argument 2 and 3 incorrectly. On the declaration of your predicate the arguments order are _LIST, FORMAT 0, NEW LIST, OUT FORMAT_ and on your `printLists/2` call you use _LIST, NEW LIST, FORMAT 0, OUT FORMAT_ 

Once again thank you for your time

Comment: @PedroPereira thanks for spotting that. At the last minute I had swapped some arguments around to get all the inputs first and the outputs last, and evidently didn't fix it on the actual call. I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this mechanism is that, in this context, and for some reason, the `format/2` column positioning seems not to work as expected between multiple calls to `format/2`. However, if you use the `~@` format specifier, it will actually work [OK, it *may* work, as I was only able to try it on SWI Prolog which has the same `format/2` options].

The `~@` format option tells `format` to call the next argument as a Prolog predicate.

Here's an illustration. Instead of this:

```
printElement(L/C) :- format('~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', [L, C]).
printElement(L) :- format('~t~a~t~20+|~t', L).
```

Try this:

```
printElement(L) :-
    (   L = A/B
    ->  format('~@', print2(A, B))
    ;   format('~@', print1(L))
    ).

print2(L, C) :- format('~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', [L, C]).
print1(L) :- format('~t~a~t~20+|', L).   % Not sure why you have the extra '~t'
                                         %  in your format; I removed it
```

Note that I put the `if-else` construct in to avoid the second `printElement/1` from matching the `L/C` form.

Comment: Thank you for your time answering my multiple questions.
The extra '~t' was just for testing if it would change the result.
Although I understand you answer, I am getting the same result.
On the top level, if I call: `printElement(foo),printElement(test),printElement(baa).`
I get:

"(tab space) foo (tab space)| test | baa| "

Once again thank you for your time

Comment: @PedroPereira ok, that's unfortunate. Obviously a difference in behavior between the two Prologs. It's also unfortunate that `format` doesn't seem to operate relative to the current cursor position when doing `~N+`. If I think of anything else, I'll let you know. This seems like a basic capability that should work simply somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which works in SWI Prolog. You'll need to try it in SICSTUS Prolog to see if it works there as well. Just make the following predicate updates to your original solution:

```
printElement(L/C) :- format('~0+~t~a - ~a~t~20+|', [L, C]).  % added '~0+'
printElement(L) :- format('~0+~t~a~t~20+|', L).              % added '~0+'

printList([]) :- format('~n').   % [] argument unnecessary in format, so removed
```

In `printElement`, I added a `~0+` at the beginning of each format string (atom)  to establish the relative column position before the rest of the formatting occurs. If this doesn't work under SICSTUS, you can try `~1+`. But in SWI, I get the expected output using `~0+`. I like this solution better than pasting together an arbitrarily long format string.

Original code test:

```
?- printList([a,b,c]).
         a          |b|c|
true.
```

Updated code test:

```
?- printList([a,b,c]).
         a          |         b          |         c          |
true.
```